# Input is a number, but is treated as string, How to convert to make a sum and use it in a Try and catch throw error to check the entries JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need your help to go to a try and catch statements and throw errors in an if/else, with user input. The problem is that "the else block" does not execute. The main objective is to check if it is `number` to `parseInt` and then use the input values to a sum. I first check if it is `empty`, Then I check if it is `letter or strings` and after, I check if it is a `number` at last, in the else statement.

The problem is that the input is always treated as a string, and never goes to the else statement. How to fix that, once all inputs are numbers ?

Obs.: The catch block and both throw errors are working fine.

```javascript
window.onload = () => {
  const button = document.getElementById('button')
  button.addEventListener('click', verifyEntries)
}

function verifyEntries () {
  try {
    const value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
    const value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;

    if (value1 === '' || value2 === ''){ // check if the input is empty
      throw new Error(' value 1 and value 2 must be filled !'); // **this line execute**
    } else if (typeof value1 !== 'number' && typeof value2 !== 'number'){ // check if is "alphabetical"
      throw new Error(' both values should be numbers'); // **this line execute**line 17
    } else { // **this block does not executes - the input stays as strings**
      const result = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `Resultado: ${result}`; // I get the error message line 17
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert('Atention!  ' + error)
  } finally {
    document.getElementById('value1').value = ''
    document.getElementById('value2').value = ''
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Inform two numbers to sum:</p>
  <label for='value1'>Valor 1:</label>
  <input type='text' id='value1'>
  <label for='value2'>Valor 2:</label>
  <input type='text' id='value2'>
  <button id='button'>Sum</button>
  <p id='result'></p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The `value` property of an `HTMLInputElement` is _always_ a string. Using `typeof` is not useful. Why not simply use `<input type="number">` and the `valueAsNumber` property?

Comment: There's the number 5 and the string "5", and they're different. `5 === "5"` will evaluate to false, for instance. (However, `5 == "5"` evaluates to true... but that's a quirk of javascript. Don't use `==`.)

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for your help. After searching a lot in this site, I found a good alternative, I have checked and is working fine. Take a look.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const button = document.getElementById('button')
  button.addEventListener('click', verifyEntries)
}

function verifyEntries () {
  try {
    const value1 = Number(document.getElementById('value1').value);
    const value2 = Number(document.getElementById('value2').value);
    console.log(value1, value2);

    if (value1 == '' || value2 == ''){ // check if the input is empty
      throw new Error(' value 1 and value 2 must be filled !'); // this line execute
    } else if (isNaN(value1) || isNaN(value2)){ // check if is "alphabetical"
      throw new Error(' both values should be numbers'); // this line execute
    } else {
      //  parseInt(value1) && parseInt(value2) - this line is not necessary.
      console.log(value1, value2);
      const result = (value1) + (value2);
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `Resultado: ${result}`; // is working now 
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert('Atention!  ' + error)
  } finally {
    document.getElementById('value1').value = ''
    document.getElementById('value2').value = ''
  }
}
```